# Trigger to update existing record when a new record inserted in to the table with the same id

Tags: oracle, triggers

//For eg:
//Time_Entry Table
`ID='SAM' Work Order='WO1234' LoginTime='MM-DD-YYHH:MMAM'; LogoutTme=NULL;`

Comment: When a same user (SAM) wants to work on another WorkOrder, the system creates another entry in Time_Entry table. After the insert I want to logout the same user from previous work order number. Please help write a trigger to fulfil this scenario.

Comment: Please update your question to present a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  And people will be much more willing to "help" when you present what you've tried so far.  Otherwise you are not asking for "help" but instead asking others to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that "system" creates entries one-by-one, then a row-level trigger might do what you want.

Sample table and trigger:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (c_user        varchar2(10),
  3     working_order varchar2(10),
  4     login_time    date,
  5     logout_time   date
  6    );

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_test
  2    before insert on test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    update test set
  6      logout_time = sysdate
  7      where c_user = :new.c_user
  8        and logout_time is null;
  9  end;
 10  /

Trigger created.
```

Insert one row:

```
SQL> insert into test values ('SAM', 'WO1234', sysdate, null);

1 row created.
```

`SAM` now gets another work order:

```
SQL> insert into test values ('SAM', 'WO5555', sysdate, null);

1 row created.
```

Table contents (I'm setting date format; you don't have to do that):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from test order by login_time;

C_USER     WORKING_OR LOGIN_TIME          LOGOUT_TIME
---------- ---------- ------------------- -------------------
SAM        WO1234     19.04.2022 21:53:29 19.04.2022 21:54:50
SAM        WO5555     19.04.2022 21:54:50

SQL>
```

Looks OK.

---

But, if "system" creates more than a single work order, trigger will see the table *mutating* and raise an error:

```
SQL> insert into test
  2    select 'SAM', 'WO6666', sysdate, null from dual union all
  3    select 'SAM', 'WO7777', sysdate, null from dual;
insert into test
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04091: table SCOTT.TEST is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_BI_TEST", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_BI_TEST'


SQL>
```

---

What should you do? Abandon the trigger idea. When "system" creates a new entry in that table, let it first log off previous work order and then insert new work order(s), i.e.

```
update test set logout_time = sysdate where c_user = 'SAM' and logout_time is null;
insert into test ...
```